# In iOS, should UIImageView.image be set to "nil" before assigning it a new UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

In iOS, should UIImageView.image be set to "nil" before assigning it a new UIImage?

```
myUIImageView.image = nil;

myUIImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"talkButton.png"];
```

Would this be the correct way to do it?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to assign nil, and it's not really a bad habit to get into in some cases (maybe not when setting a property), but it's not required.  Just don't do like some people and think you have to alloc/init a value there to "create" the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about reference counting, the explicit assignment to `nil` is unnecessary; under ARC the `.image` property will automatically handle that for you (when the new image is assigned).

Where setting to `nil` *is* useful is where you want to explicitly mark the image as no longer in use, but do not want to remove / delete the `UIImageView` itself or set a new image.  In those cases, setting `.image = nil` is a good idea.

Comment: If you're property is declared to be retain or copy, you won't have to worry about releasing it at all, ARC or no.

Answer (score 2):

No need to set a property to nil before changing it if you are using the setter. The setter will release the current reference before assigning the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You will, though, see this pattern frequently when you are setting an image asynchronously in a view that is reused (such as a table/collection view cell). You don't appear to be doing that here, so setting the `image` to `nil` here doesn't accomplish much, but the aforementioned scenario is one situation where clearing the `image` is quite important because (a) if a cell is reused, the previous image may still be there, but (b) if you're retrieving images asynchronously, it may take a moment for the new image to be loaded, so you will see the previous image momentarily unless you `nil` it.

For example, you would want to set the image to `nil` in this situation:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // configure the rest of the cell

    // ok, now set the image

    cell.myUIImageView.image = nil; // clear the image in case the cell has been reused

    [self.networkQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        UIImage *image = [self getImageFromNetworkForIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.myUIImageView.image = image;
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I have ran into the problem you're describing. "The image is still there in a resuable tableview cell". I put an image placeholder which is a bit bigger than the image i want to display in the cell, when the image returns asynchroniously it just displays above the placeholder, instead of doing it "instead". I set the image to nil, before setting the new image, and this does not help. Is there a solution to my problem ?